# Forgotten series... augmented mental powers

Tags: story-identification

Hi I read the first of what I presume is a series at a time the second book was not published. First probably 2016? I have since forgotten the author and title.

Plot... Experiments in hard wired brain stimulation leads participants to unexpectedly unlock the brains capacity for various 'powers'. Different subjects express these new powers in different ways. Government agencies seek to control these individuals but they fight back by taking control of a military stronghold in a mountain.

There was a girl that had unique abilities amongst the several factions that appeared. At the end of the book that  I read she was kidnapped.
Does this ring a bell with anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve your question by reviewing the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details, like what the cover looked like, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but could it be [The God Wave by Patrick Hemstreet](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/26156475-the-god-wave).

[image: The God Wave]

This was published in 2016 so it matches your time frame, and it is the first book in a  trilogy though so far only the second book has been published. The last book is expected next year. The name refers to brain waves - it is by amplifying brain waves that the scientists create the super powers.

I have the book but I remember very little about it. Skimming it I find it matches most of your points. To quote from the Goodreads summary:

> For decades, scientists have speculated about the untapped potential of the human brain. Now, neuroscientist Chuck Brenton has made an astonishing breakthrough. He has discovered the key—the crucial combination of practice and conditioning—to access the incredible power dormant in ninety percent of our brains. Applying his methods to test subjects, he has stimulated abilities that elevate brain function to seemingly “godlike” levels.

There are good superhumans called the *Zetas* (named after the brain waves called  [zeta waves](http://eegpedia.org/index.php?title=Zeta_waves)) and a group who rebel called the *Deeps*. The rebels do indeed retreat to a base in a mountain. They are led by *Sara Crowell*.

The powerful woman who is kidnapped is *Chen Lanfen*.

Comment: Yes that's it, Thank John I can now order the next book. Cheers Grant.

Comment: @Wildman if this is the book please will you click the tick mark to the left of my answer. That marks the answer as accepted. Thanks :-)